# After Changes to Google Analytics Tracking Code - Returning Users Considered New Users?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics

I need to change a piece of code in my Universal Analytics snippet from:

`ga("create", "UA-######-#", {"cookieDomain":".ourdomainname.com"});`

to:

`ga("create", "UA-######-#", {"cookieDomain":"auto"});`

My question is - once I make this change, will all returning users (about 1/3 of my traffic) suddenly be considered brand new first-time visitors and get a whole new Analytics cookie? Or any other problems or inconsistencies with data and tracking visitors before this change vs. after? Very little info about this out there online ...